# how can i add vertical line in the plot (R ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

in R ggplot2,how can i  add vertical line in the plot :
my code for plot2 don't work,anyone can help? thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
#create data.frame
mdate<-seq(from=as.Date("2020-1-31"),
    to=as.Date("2020-12-31"),
    by="1 month")
mvalue<-rnorm(12)
df<-data.frame(mdate,mvalue)
#plot1: when i add vertical line by month,it's ok
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=mdate,y=mvalue))+geom_line()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=df$mdate))
#plot2: when i add vertical line by quarter
#       it's can't work
vline<-seq(from=as.Date("2020-3-31"),
                  to=as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                  by="3 month")

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=mdate,y=mvalue))+geom_line()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=vline))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `xintercept = vline` inside `aes()`. `aes()` is for mapping **columns from your data** to graphical aesthetics, so `ggplot` is looking in your data for a column named `vline`, which doesn't exist.

`vline` isn't in your data frame, so don't put it inside `aes()`. `geom_vline(xintercept = vline)` should work fine.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mdate, y = mvalue)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = vline)
```

[image]